# Not able to add new method to inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

Why is the following piece of code not working?

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class TestInner {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>(){

        private String sample = null;
        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }

        public void setText(String t1){
            sample = t1;
        }

    };
    // compiler error - Method is undefined for the type Comparator<String> 
    comp.setText("xyz"); 

}

}
```

I have used Comparator just in the sample code. The same is happening with Comparator of any object.

I'm creating an inner class that has implemented the Comparator interface, why is it now allowing me to add new methods here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this isn't allowed is because you have a `Comparator` on the left hand side of your `=` and a `Comparator` doesn't have a `setText` method.  To solve this issue, you'll have to name a class with a `setText` method and use that named class on the left hand side.  For example, this code will compile:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyComparator comp = new MyComparator();
        // compiler error - Method is undefined for the type Comparator<String> 
        comp.setText("xyz");

    }

    private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        private String sample = null;

        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }

        public void setText(String t1) {
            sample = t1;
        }    
    }        
}
```

---

Note that this code will still fail to compile because you didn't put `MyComparator` on the left hand side:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparator comp = new MyComparator();
        // compiler error - Method is undefined for the type Comparator<String>
        comp.setText("xyz");

    }

    private static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        private String sample = null;

        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }

        public void setText(String t1) {
            sample = t1;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an inner class it doesn't have a type that you can directly use.

You are assigning your inner class to a variable of type `Comparator` so when you reference that variable you can only access the methods defined by the type `Comparator`.

If you want to use other methods externally you should create a separate class that `implements Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparator` interface does not have a `setText()` method. You have declared the type of the variable as `Comparator`, not some customer class, so the only methods you may call are those belonging to `Comparator`

Answer (score 0):

Because Comparator doesn't declare a setText() method and you are trying to invoke the method using a Comparator reference variable .